# python beautifulsoup get footer from chinese website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the data from a Chinese website. I've found where it is in the html, but need help pulling out the text. I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = 'http://sbj.speiyou.com/search/index/subject:/grade:12/gtype:time'
r = requests.get(page)

r.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

div = soup.find('div', class_='pagination mtop40')
```

The data i'm looking for is the `16` in `1/16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex on `div.text` is one option. The following regex looks for any digits followed by a forward slash followed by more digits.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+\/\d+')
matches = re.search(pattern, div.text)
num = matches.group(0) # num = 1/16 here
print num.split('/')[1]
```

**OR**

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+\/(\d+)') # Group the needed data in the regex pattern
matches = re.search(pattern, div.text)
print matches.group(0)
```

Comment: How do i get the text out? `div.text` is giving me an error. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
`

Comment: @jason_cant_code Error suggests that the variable `div` is None. Does your code still have the line `div = soup.find('div', class_='pagination mtop40')`?

Comment: i figured it out. it was a library i didn't install.